# Identifying properties

Tags: c#, boolean, win-universal-app, observablecollection, identity

I want to store the 3 task in a collection but also able to identify them in the collection. i.e. which "link, image, title" belongs to favorite and which ones belongs to new and which one belongs to featured just as it is on the list of Url. if you can show me with code i will be more than grateful.

Here is my code:

```
 private List<string> urlList()
    {
        List<string> urls = new List<string>
        {
            "http:favorite.com,
            "http://new.com",
            "http://feature.com"
        };
        return urls;
    }

 async Task GetData()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36");
        List<string> taskurl = urlList();
        IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTaskQuery =
            from url in taskurl select ProcessURL(url, client);
        List<Task<int>> downloadTask = downloadTaskQuery.ToList();
        while (downloadTask.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<int> firstFinishTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTask);
            downloadTask.Remove(firstFinishTask);
            int lenght = await firstFinishTask;
        }
    }

 private async Task<int> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var urlContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var article = new Observable<Article>();
            foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(i => i.Name == "div" && i.GetAttributeValue("class", "").StartsWith("foo")))
            {
        return something;
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking; is `Category` a property of the `Article` class?

Comment: lets say i am making three calls from the web and since it is not an API or XML/JSON request i am making... I need to categories the articles by my self. I am using multiple task http request, I have an array of 3 url. I want to add the content of those 3 url to one ObservableCollection but still be able to differentiate all the articles to the category i want them.

Comment: I think you should add a `Category` property to the `Article` class. Then, you can categorize it where you create each article. Does that make sense for what you're trying to do?

Comment: for instance Latest News will have{link, title, image} trending news will have same properties as latest news. I want to use one DataModel class for all the categories as well as one Observable collection instead of making a class for all the categories with different Collections and Different Http request for each. And since i am using Pivot to display the 3 categories. I hope you understand.

Comment: I think I get what you're asking now, but I don't know enough to provide a decent answer for you. Sorry I can't help more

Comment: Let Article Class have dictionary-->Dictionary<Category(a string), ObeservableCollection<CategorisedArticle>>. So you will be having OBCollection of dictionaries.Hope it makes sense. Let me know if you have queries

Comment: I think, what you want maybe is the data class for source grouped list? If yes, I can wrote an answer to show you how to implement a grouped source ListView.

Comment: Grace fenge Yes. I am going to update the question. I think i can be clearer with the research i have made. the question will change to something else now. @LevetoCode i am changing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed yesterday, if a grouped list can solve your problem, you could do it for example like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="listViewItems" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
    <DataTemplate x:Name="listViewItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookAddress}" FontSize="20" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind listViewItems.View}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listViewItemTemplate}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Red" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

code behind is quite clear:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    listViewItems.Source = Headers.GetItemsGrouped();
}
```

I find from your code that you put the data in a string List named "urls", I will continue to use this List as data source in my "Headers" class, and so is my "Headers" class like this:

```
public class Headers
{
    public string HeaderTitle { get; set; }

    public Headers()
    {
        HeaderTitle = string.Empty;
    }

    private static List<string> urls = new List<string>
    {
        "http://favorite.com",
        "http://new.com",
        "http://feature.com",
        "http://favorite.book1.com",
        "http://new.book2.com",
        "http://feature.book3.com",
        "http://favorite.book4.com",
        "http://new.book5.com",
    };

    public static ObservableCollection<BookList> GetCollection()
    {
        ObservableCollection<BookList> myBookList = new ObservableCollection<BookList>();
        foreach (var book in urls)
        {
            myBookList.Add(new BookList(book));
        }
        return myBookList;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> GetItemsGrouped()
    {
        ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();

        var query = from item in GetCollection()
                    group item by item.BookAddress[9] into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };

        foreach (var g in query)
        {
            GroupInfoList info = new GroupInfoList();

            switch (g.GroupName.ToString())
            {
                case "v":
                    info.Key = "Favorite";
                    break;

                case "w":
                    info.Key = "New";
                    break;

                case "a":
                    info.Key = "Feature";
                    break;

                default:
                    info.Key = g.GroupName;
                    break;
            }

            foreach (var item in g.Items)
            {
                info.Add(item);
            }
            groups.Add(info);
        }
        return groups;
    }
}
```

And also my `BookList` class and `GroupInfoList` are like this:

```
public class BookList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _BookAddress;

    public string BookAddress
    {
        get { return _BookAddress; }
        set
        {
            _BookAddress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BookAddress");
        }
    }

    public BookList(string name)
    {
        this.BookAddress = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class GroupInfoList : List<object>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```

The `BookList` class is for the item of `ListView`, if you want to show more details in each item, you can add properties in this class. And the `GroupInfoList` class is just for the `Key` of each group.

In my sample, your Uri's format should always follow these patterns:

- "http://favorite.(balabla).com"
- "http://new.(balabla).com"
- "http://feature.(balabla).com"

You can modify the code in the `GetItemsGrouped()` method of `Headers` class to meet your expected pattern.

This is the result of this sample:

[image]

In case you want to test my sample, here is [it(Grouped List)](https://github.com/GraceFeng/Grouped-List).

Comment: Instead of using case operation I use the if(url.contains("unique" eg. New){set isNew to true} you get what I mean. Then I can make a "new" collection then use linq query to select from the master collection where new is true and I will make another a "favourite" collection and select from the master collection where favourite is true. You get what I mean.