# UWP - Update listview source dynamic from code behind

Tags: c#, listview, windows-10-universal

I have a group item. Then, each group in group item, i put it into a listview

```
var Groups = query.GroupBy(query => query.Name);
foreach (var group in Groups)
            {
                if (group.records.Count() > 2)
                {
                    ListView listview = new ListView();
                    var itemsource = new ObservableCollection<FileProperties>();
                    var header = "";
                    foreach (var item in group.records)
                    {
                        header = item.Name;
                        itemsource.Add(new FileProperties(item.Name, item.Size, item.DateModified, item.Hash, item.Path, item.IsOrigin));
                    }
                    listview.ItemsSource = itemsource;
                    var itemsTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["Show"];
                    listview.ItemTemplate = itemsTemplate;
                    //test is mother listview
                    test.Items.Add(listview);
                }
            }
```

Now, i have a question, how can i update listview UI if i change value in group items without reset mother listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ListView` can be grouped by using [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). There is no need to create a child `ListView` for each group of the parent `ListView`.

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704277/identifying-properties/36737507#36737507) shows how to create a grouped `ListView`, you may take a look. Or there are a bunch of demos on internet, you can googling them.

But the most important point here is that by using the default grouped `ListView`, we can simply create one data collection for the whole `ListView`,  modify the items source collection to update the grouped children automatically, we don't need to create `ObservableCollection`s for each group any more.